# Basic process for closing up a window?

Tags: windows

We've got an addition in our house that original owners went a little above & beyond on amount of windows and we're wanting to close off one of the west facing windows. Exterior is aluminum 8" siding, interior is a panel variant over drywall. This is essentially how I plan on attacking:

- Removing interior casing and exterior aluminum cladding/trim
- Sawzall fasteners and (hopefully) remove windows/frames w/o breaking glass
- add blocking "inside" of window frame
- sheeting on exterior (thickness will be whatever is needed to match current plane)
- moisture barrier over new sheeting
- Patch in aluminum siding (sourcing aluminum siding is proving to be the most difficult, but i have a few sources that look likely)
- Add insulation on the interior
- patch in/match wall
- Celebrate

Is there anything im missing from a high level?

Comment: Make sure you pull siding back in random distances (for each course of siding) from each side of the window opening. Otherwise it will look like a patch when you see the vertical lines where the siding overlaps.

Comment: Patching is easy, it is the matching that is hard.  Different idea, leave the window in.  Add the insulation plus the other adds, but use small door/large picture frame  on the inside.  A picture or something can be place in the window pointing out.

Comment: @FreeMan good callout - fortunately that wall is only about 6.5' wide, so ill probably end up just replacing the entire length of siding, or at least most of it (assuming I can source it)